# ReactiveSwift: How to write a Task Scheduler

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-cocoa

I am trying to create a scheduler to consume some data.

The scheduler will have to be able to:

- send an event each time data should be consumed manually
- send an event each time data should be consumed automatically after some time has elapsed after the last consumption

I have modelled the manual consumption with a `MutableProperty`

```
 let consume = MutableProperty<Void>()
```

and I am trying to model the automatic consumption with a `SignalProducer`

```
 let timer = SignalProducer<Void, NoError>
```

I can get the first time that I need to consume that data by combining the latest values of these two producers like

```
SignalProducer.combineLatest(consume.producer, timer)
    .take(first: 1)
    .map() { _ in return () }
```

That way whichever comes first, a manual consumption or an automatic one the producer will send a value.

I can't figure out how I will be able to do this perpetually.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 5):

You can start a timer using the global timer functions defined in `ReactiveSwift`

```
public func timer(interval: TimeInterval, on scheduler: DateSchedulerProtocol) -> SignalProducer<Date, NoError>
```

To combine the timer with the consume property:

```
let interval = 10.0
let timerSignal: SignalProducer<Date, NoError> = timer(interval: interval, on: QueueScheduler.main)
let consume = MutableProperty<Void>()

timerSignal.combineLatest(with: consume.producer).startWithValues { (date, v) in
    print("triggered at time: \(date)")
}
```

This way you can trigger the print block manually by setting the `value` property on consume, or by waiting for the timer event.

Comment: that doesn't exactly answer the question. The interval between consume events should be 10 seconds meaning that if 10 seconds pass after the latest consume event a new event should be generated. What your code does (and the snippet I provided too) is that no matter what each time 10 seconds pass a new event will be generated. e.g: Lets say that the timer starts at 0 and a manual consume event arrives at 4. The timer will fire at 10 creating an automated consume event but I wanted it to fire at 14 (10 seconds passed between events)

Comment: I was able to make an approximation of what I wanted to do by using a polling producer that fires every 0.5 seconds and mapping each consume event with the timeIntervarlSince1970 that it originate. Each time any of the two, timer or consume property, fire an event I simple compare the current timeIntervalSince1970 with the latest generated consume event timeInterval, if the difference is greater than 10 seconds, I fire a new consume event. I was hopping for a more elegant solution though

Comment: How to stop this timer ?

Comment: @franck I guess you got to get `Disposable` reference and dispose it when needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap timer into SignalProducer

```swift
func timerProducer() -> SignalProducer<Void, Never> {
    return SignalProducer<Void, Never> { observer, disposable in
        let timer = Timer(timeInterval: 10, repeats: true) { timer in
            if disposable.hasEnded {
                timer.invalidate()
            } else {
                observer.send(value: ())
            }
        }
        RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .common)
    }
}
```

Note: If you starting this producer from NON-main thread, you need add it to RunLoop. Otherwise it will not get triggered.